# Question on logarithm Exponentiation

Tags: logarithms

I know it's not the best title but I had no idea how to be specific about it.

Basically what I'm looking for is a rule that states how $$\log^2(a^{f(x)})$$ works. Does it become $$f(x)\log^2(a)$$ or $$f^2(x)\log^2(a)$$?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Does $\log^2 u$ mean $(\log u)^2$, or $\log (\log u)$?

Comment: $\log^2u$ Means $(log u)^2$

Comment: Thought so. And now, if you write it $$\Bigl( \log \bigl(a^{f(x)}\bigr)\Bigr)^2,$$ can you see what is correct?

Comment: @DanielFischer yup. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $log^2(a^{f(x)})=log(a^{f(x)})log(a^{f(x)})$. It follows that

$log^2(a^{f(x)})=f(x)log(a)f(x)log(a)=f^2(x)log^2(a)$. Therefore it is the second one.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

With full parenthesis,

$$\left(\log(a^{f(x)})\right)^2.$$

By a rule of logarithms,

$$\log(a^{f(x)})=f(x)\log(a).$$

Then distributing,

$$\left(f(x)\log(a)\right)^2=f^2(x)\log^2(a).$$